# Load HTML file from a linked java library into Android webview

Tags: java, android, html, webview, jar

I have a `webview` into which I'd like to load an HTML file that comes from an external java library.

That is, my project includes a java library that, besides a bunch of Java classes, also contains a bunch of HTML (and related) files inside its `resource` folder. I'd like to load these files into my `webview`.

I know how to load HTML files when they are located in the `assets` folder: you simply run `webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/your-file.html")`.

I do not know how to write the `url` to access resources in the linked JAR. The [docs do not help much.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl(java.lang.String))

Comment: you may read the HTML file to a String, and load it into webView for example

Comment: This won't for linked resources, like linked `.css` or `.js` files.

Comment: that's right. Also you can copy all resources into some directory keeping the structure, and then load it from the file, which you copied.